# Route reloads entire page and view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http

I am developing an app, and in the app, there are some "utility" buttons that when clicked will, say, show the user some information.

For example, a question-mark button, that when clicked, shows the user some "quick tips".

The app is heavily data-driven, so I wanted to avoid having extra hidden elements that just show based on a flag whenever the user clicks a button.

So, I have a `div` element with an `ng-view` tag that will populate with `quick-tips.html` whenever the user clicks the question-mark button.

The routing code looks like this:

```
whiteboard.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/quick-tips', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/quick-tips.html',
            controller: mainController
        }); 
}]);
```

Here's a shortened version of my HTML:

```
<a href="#quick-tips"><!-- bootstrap question mark glyphicon --></a>

<div ng-view></div>

<!-- a bunch of other HTML markup (this refreshes for some reason when the route is called and the view is updated) -->
```

My issue is that when the link is clicked, the entire page refreshes, and then populates the view. It breaks the user-experience, I think. Is this supposed to happen? If so, is there a way to avoid it?

I looked into using `$routeProvider resolve`, but it didn't look like that would fix the issue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to my own question, in case anyone else has this issue.

I was using a `base` tag in my HTML:

```
<base href="<!-- etc. -->">
```

This caused the page to reload every time when using routes.